# Recurrence $f_{n+2}=af_{n+1}+bf_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

> Solve the recurrence $$f_{n+2}=af_{n+1}+bf_n\qquad n\in\Bbb N_0\tag{1}$$
>   Where $a,b>0$ and $f_0,f_1$ are given.

I know that if $$F_{n+1}=c_nF_n+d_n$$ then $$F_n=F_0\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}c_k+\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}d_m\prod_{k=m+1}^{n-1}c_k\ .$$
But I am unsure of how to find a solution to the recurrence in question. I am fairly certain that a closed form exists, because the Fibonacci sequence $F_n$ (which is given by the case $a=b=f_1=1$ and $f_0=0$) has an explicit solution, namely 
$$F_n=\frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt5}$$ where
$$\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2,\qquad \psi=\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\,.$$
Admittedly, I do not know how to prove said result, but I'm sure there is some sort of generalization of the proof to solve my recurrence.

I've defined the generating function
$$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}f_nx^n$$
and shown that 
$$f(x)=\frac{f_0+(f_1-af_0)x}{1-ax-bx^2}\ .$$
So of course $$f_n=\frac1{n!}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^n\frac{f_0+(f_1-af_0)x}{1-ax-bx^2}\,\Bigg|_{x=0}$$
but that is way too inefficient. Is there a nice closed form solution for $(1)$? Thanks.

Comment: The usual method is to study the [characteristic polynomial](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial).  As this is quadratic in your case, you can work it all out quite explicitly.

Comment: @lulu could you show me how (in an answer)?

Comment: I attached a link which works it all out.  That link uses the Fibonacci recursion as a concrete example.

Comment: Related, the most efficient way to compute the $n$-th Fibonacci number (or in general the $n$-th term of any non-trivial recurrence relation) is to use [the matrix form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1891637/21820) and [iterated squaring](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1698898/21820), rather than the closed form, because exponentiation of irrationals to arbitrary precision is actually very computationally expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start by finding two geometric sequences that solve

$$x^{n+2} = ax^{n+1}+bx^n\tag{A.}$$

Solving for $x$, we get

\begin{align}
   x^{n+2} &= ax^{n+1}+bx^n \\
   x^2 &= ax+b \\
   x^2 - ax -b &= 0 \\
   x &= \frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}
\end{align}

From here on, we have to assume that $a^2+4b \ne 0$.

Then $f_n = \alpha\left(\dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}\right)^n
           + \beta\left(\dfrac{a - \sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}\right)^n$

will solve $f_{n+2}=af_{n+1}+bf_n$ for all $n \ge 0$.

We still need to solve  $f_0 = \alpha + \beta$ and 
$f_1=\alpha\left(\dfrac{a + \sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}\right)
           + \beta\left(\dfrac{a - \sqrt{a^2+4b}}{2}\right)$ for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but that is relatively trivial.