# Solve non-homogeneous recurrence $x_{n+2} - 2x_{n+1} + x_n = 8$

Tags: recurrence-relations, homogeneous-equation

I'm trying to solve this recurrence $x_{n+2} - 2x_{n+1} + x_n = 8$, but the solution of the homogeneous is $a_n=b+cn$, and I don't know how to change it to find the non-homogeneous solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Ansatz $x_n=kn^2$ so$$8=k[n^2+4n+4-2n^2-4n-2+n^2]=2k\implies k=4.$$

Comment: Great, it worked! Whenever I have a non-homogeneous recurrence whose f (x) is a constant, will this solution work?

Comment: @GabrielDelgado There's no general rule, but a useful tip is to try the next simplest thing to the homogeneous case.

Comment: @NeatMath That's already included in the homogeneous solution.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I did have a lecture notes pdf file on my dead computer where there is some example when guess work doesn't work. I'll show you the example when I recover the file.

Comment: @NeatMath Cool, I look forward to seeing it. As with differential equations, no toolkit is a panacea.

Answer (score 2):

$$x_{n+2} - 2x_{n+1} + x_n = 8\tag{1}$$
Set $n=n+1$
$$x_{n+3}-2x_{n+2}+x_{n+1}=8$$
Subtract the two equations
$$x_{n+3}-2x_{n+2}+x_{n+1}-x_{n+2} + 2x_{n+1} - x_n=0$$
$$x_{n+3}-3x_{n+2}+3x_{n+1}-x_n=0$$
Characteristic equation is
$$\lambda^3-3\lambda^2+3\lambda-1=0\to (\lambda-1)^3=0\to \lambda=1$$
and finally
$$x_n=an^2+bn+c\tag{2}$$

---

**edit**

from $(1)$ we get $x_0=8+2x_1-x_2$

from $(2)$ we have $x_0=c,\;x_1=a+b+c;\;x_2=4a+2b+c$

putting all together
$$\begin{cases}
c=8+2x_1-x_2\\
a+b+c=x_1\\
4a+2b+c=x_2\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$\begin{cases}
a+b+8+2x_1-x_2=x_1\to a+b=x_2-x_1-8\\
4a+2b+8+2x_1-x_2=x_2\to 4a+2b=2x_2-2x_1-8\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$\begin{cases}
a+b=x_2-x_1-8\\
2a+b=x_2-x_1-4\\
\end{cases}
$$
subtracting the two equations, we get $a=4$ so the $(2)$ becomes
$$x_n=4n^2+bn+c$$

Comment: Strange that I agree with the way you solved it, but we didn't find $a = 4$

Comment: @GabrielDelgado With arbitrary $a$ we're only solving the weaker recurrence relation Raffaele derived, so the solution set is more general. We really need to show this works iff $a=4$.

Comment: @GabrielDelgado I managed to get $a=4$

Comment: @J.G. I managed to get $a=4$

Answer (score 2):

If the non-homogeneous part is constant you can always take the difference and make it homogeneous.  In your case,

$$(\mathbb E-1)^2 x_n = 8 \implies (\mathbb E-1)^3 x_n = (\mathbb E - 1)8=0$$

And you get your characteristic function immediately which is $(\lambda-1)^3=1$.

Here $\mathbb E$ is the forward shift operator, $\mathbb E^i x_n = x_{n+i}, \forall i \in \mathbb N$.

For a non-constant $f(x)$ example, check out [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3906793/is-it-possible-to-solve-this-recurrence-equation/3909236#3909236).

Comment: Right. See also [this clean sketch of the general solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1414669/21820) as well as [this related post about the forward difference operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2319671/21820).

Answer (score 0):

Another way is applying unilateral $\mathcal{Z}$-transform which is defined as $$X(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x[n]z^{-n}$$The equation is $$x[n+2] -2x[n+1] +x[n] = 8u[n]$$We can easily show that the following properties holds:$$\mathcal{Z}\{\alpha^nu[n]\} = \frac{1}{1-\alpha z^{-1}} \\ \mathcal{Z}\{x[n+1]\} = zX(z) - zx[0]\implies\mathcal{Z}\{x[n+2]\} = z^2X(z) - z^2x[0] - zx[1] \\ \mathcal{Z}\{nx[n]\} = -z\frac{dX(z)}{dz}\\ \mathcal{Z}\{x[n-1]\} = z^{-1}X(z) + x[-1] \\ \mathcal{Z}\{\delta[n]\}  = 1$$Applying the transform to the equation yields $$z^2X(z) - z^2x[0] - zx[1] - 2(zX(z) - zx[0]) +X(z) = \frac{8}{1-z^{-1}}$$For convenience, let $x[0] = a$ and $x[1] = b$. Partial fraction decomposition gives $$X(z) = a + \frac{8}{(z-1)^3} + \frac{8 - a + b}{(z-1)^2} + \frac{b}{z-1}$$Taking the inverse transform gives $$x[n] = a\delta[n] + bu[n-1] + (8 - a + b)(n-1)u[n-1] + 8(\frac{1}{2}(n-2)(n-1)u[n-1])$$Which can be written as $$x[n] = a - 4n - an + bn + 4n^2 = 4n^2 + n(b-a-4) + a$$
It can be verified by [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20a%28n%2B2%29%3D%208%20%2B%202a%28n%2B1%29-%20a%28n%29). Note that the counterpart of the Laplace transform for discrete-time signals is the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform.